# Video stream sideways on some browser/device combinations

Tags: javascript, windows, html, mediastream

I'm calling `getUserMedia()` to get a video stream and simply setting the `stream` as the `srcObject` of a video element.

Specifically on Chrome on 2 different Windows Tablets, in Portrait mode the video is side ways.

I can't find any orientation info in the stream or video track objects and the width and height track info match the video element and are accurate to the aspect ratio track info.

You can duplicate with https://camera.stackblitz.io

How do I get the orientation info from the stream or logically rotate the video?

Edit:

I do not want the orientation of the device or screen, but of the video stream. Maybe "rotation" is the right verbiage.
In other words how do I know when to rotate the video without a human looking at it?

Edit 2:

"Chrome on Windows Tablet in Portrait mode" is just what I experienced I don't know if the issue is isolated to that or the issue is with every Windows tablet but the main question is how do I tell if the video is sideways or rotated?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I'm experiencing the exact same problem now.

Comment: The "solution" for me was to just give the user a rotate control so if it was sideways they could fix it them self's then store that in localstore

Comment: Mmm okay bit of a problem. We have thousands of tablets. Will see what I can get and let you know if I get a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,

> Orientation is in the field of **screen** not stream.

The [Screen Orientation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/device/screen-orientation-api) provides the ability to read the screen orientation type and angle, to be informed when the screen orientation state changes, and be able to lock the screen orientation to a specific state.

In my view, one great method for managing orientation is using [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) like below:

```
/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

  //CSS

}
```

For using other methods like JavaScript or manifest please see this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation).

**Edit**

You mentioned in title of question to *Windows Tablet* and also you mentioned 
you are looking for a way for setting orientation options *without a human looking at it*.The your second condition contradicts the former.

> How we do detect device is Windows Tablet without a human looking at
>   video??

It's not possible to answer this question. I think your view about stream is wrong.

You can choose one of them at a time:

1. If you need to detect some devices like *Windows Tablet*, you can
   use some thing like *media query* or JavaScript method to detect
   device.
2. If you need to set option *without a human looking at it*, you can
   use some method like [MediaStreamTrack.applyConstraints()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints).

Comment: The orentation of the screen not helpful because, say I rotate the video when the screen is portrait, some device/bowsers show the video correct already so I'd be rotating that was already correct. How do I know when to rotate without a human looking at the video.

Comment: @WilliamLohan I updated my answer. Please see it again.

Comment: The Windows Table is just what I experienced, is it documented somewhere that Google Chrome on Windows Tablets will rotate video in portrait mode, or how do I know that every Google Chrome on Windows Tablets will do this?
I don't see any MediaTrackConstraints that set the rotation of a video.

Comment: Not "How we do detect device is Windows Tablet without a human looking at video??" but how do we tell that the video is sideways without a human looking at it?

Comment: @WilliamLohan As I mentioned before we can't  _detect device is Windows Tablet without a human looking at video_ because detecting device depends on looking. At first, video stream is passive by itself and doesn't know about OS. When a human looking at it, it becomes active and we can detect OS with some things like screen.

Comment: I don't care about Windows Tablet.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the orientation info via javascript with `screen.orientation`.
See on the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation)

Comment: This tells me the orientation of the device but does not tell me if the video accounts for that, so if I used that logic I'd be rotating video stream that were already correct on other devices or other browsers.